# Can I get Facebook user's registered email who has liked the posts posted through my FB App in my Fan page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have no idea about Facebook's API, I am not even using FB.

Suppose I have a fan page in place already; I have developed a FB app and have installed it into my fan page.

And then I post something (photos, text, or whatever) through this FB app in this fan page, and a fan likes the post, is there a way to get the fan's registered email for my app? If yes, does it depend on the user's privacy setting?

Moreover, if a fan post something on his/her own wall with some special code, can my App keep track of that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a user starts using your pp, he gets a prompt where user can select/deselect permission to share which info with your app. If user has allowed you to access contact information then you can use one of the method of facebook api to get the contact details

Comment: Thanks. When installing an App into my own page, as a FB user, I get the prompt you said. Hmm... However, if I like a post in a fan page, will I get prompt?

Comment: Well, this is what i am trying to explain, you can only see user's contact details if user has allowed you to do so. If user likes any post on your fan page, then you need to find a way so that user allows you, like a prompt or something. Its been 3 years since I did anything using FB API

Answer (score 0):

A "fan" page can not access the email of the people that simply "like" it. A user's email is not part of the public profile.

Your app can request access you the user's email. Then the user will get a prompt saying the app requests access to their email. The user has the ability to say no to this request.

A user simply liking a page will not prompt for access to their email.